# Is there a way to enable/disable logging in python inside all files

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Is there a way to enable/disable logging quickly using a global switch? I am using following code to setup logging

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='ordersLogs.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

And I am logging using this in many files.
I know we can use disable function on logging and it will disable logging for that level but to do that I need to make changes to all those files. So is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`logging.disable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.disable) is probably what you are looking for. It provides an application-level setting (applies to all the loggers you have defined), with an optional level argument that you can use to suppress logging up to a certain level (typically, you will want to get rid of nuisance logging, but keep the higher criticality lines).

Comment: Can I setup it up so that I call this logging.disable at once place and it will disable the logging for all py files? And if yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Hello, Not sure exactly how your code is organized, but basically yes, logging.disable is a application-wide setting, which means that it will apply wherever you have defined logging (in any files that are part of your application).